# What is a good pattern for reporting errors when incorrectly using a re-usable directives in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

What is a good pattern for reporting errors when writing re-usable directives in Angular?

I'm writing a few components as angular directives, with the intention of re-using them, expecting that developers will be joining this project later and not have all the information I have now about using the directive.

I'm documenting the directive and code about it's use, and I have unit tests that are basically examples of using it correctly for additional "documentation". I still want meaningful responses/exceptions to come back to a developer when they're building pages with the directive.

Is there a pattern of throwing common exceptions, or logging perhaps, that's used to help communicate mis-use of a directive to developers learning to work with it?

Comment: console.log('log message');  take a look at: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2011/05/26/console-log-say-goodbye-to-javascript-alerts-for-debugging.aspx

Comment: throw an error,there are no exceptions in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

While this is probably more of a general JS question than Angular, the same theories still apply. You should be wrapping things in try/catch/finally blocks and throwing errors where appropriate.

```
function Blah(isRequired, isOptional){
    var X = 7, Y = 0;
    try{
        Y = X * isRequired;
    }
    catch(err){
        throw new Error('You must provide a value for "isRequired"');
    }
    finally{
        //this example has none, but do cleanup things here
    }
}
```

If you want to show logging, you can use the Angular wrapper for writing to the console. It will prevent errors when using IE and trying to write to console.debug by writing them to console.log instead.

Setup:

```
myapp.config(['$logProvider', function($logProvider){
    $logProvider.debugEnabled(true);
})
.run(['$rootScope', '$log',
    function ($rootScope, $log) {
        'use strict';

        //create a reference to $log on the root scope
    $rootScope.$log = $log;
    }]);
```

Usage:

```
$scope.$log.log(message);
$scope.$log.debug(message);
$scope.$log.info(message);
$scope.$log.warn(message);
$scope.$log.error(message);
```

You can also enable/disable logging in your directives by adding an attribute. Something like data-log-enabled.

```
<div data-log-enabled my-directive>
</div>
```

In your directive, you handle it like so:

```
link: function(scope, element, attributes){
    if(attributes.logEnabled){
        scope.$log.debug('blah');
    }
}
```

This avoids unnecessary output to the console that can slow down apps, and can also help developers to minimize the amount of stuff they have to read through to find the information they need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for logging:

`console.log()`

`console.debug()`

`console.info()`

`console.warn()`

`console.error()`

These messages will be located in the debugger console

[image]

Check [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2011/05/26/console-log-say-goodbye-to-javascript-alerts-for-debugging.aspx) great article that reviews these functions

Answer (score 0):

Look at my answer here: [How do you 'require' an attribute on an angularjs directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23370448/how-do-you-require-an-attribute-on-an-angularjs-directive/23370611#23370611)

Angular uses the pattern of throwing exceptions/errors when the directives have missing attributes or are used incorrectly etc.

Comment: If you do like that jshint throw an empty block error